# MongoDB - Get last date of every distinct name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am starting MongoDB and have problems about how to create a query to filter documents by last date of every distinct name and retrieve the whole document.

I have some data into my collection (students):

```json
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61479d4bc146b1663a8f2b7d"), "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "ANA", "status" : "ACTIVE", "date1" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:14:30.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61479d88c146b1663a8f2b7e"), "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "MARIA", "status" : "ACTIVE", "date1" : ISODate("2020-08-01T04:16:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61479dc2c146b1663a8f2b7f"), "city" : "RIO DE JANEIRO", "name" : "MARIA", "status" : "ACTIVE", "date1" : ISODate("2021-02-01T11:10:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61479df1c146b1663a8f2b80"), "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "MARIA", "status" : "INACTIVE", "date1" : ISODate("2021-02-01T11:15:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61479e60c146b1663a8f2b81"), "city" : "BRASILIA", "name" : "JOHH", "status" : "ACTIVE", "date1" : ISODate("2021-06-01T01:18:00.000Z") }
```

I'm creating a query to filter status "ACTIVE" and show only most recent data for each student, showing only "city", "name", "date" and I'm trying this one using $MAX or $LAST into the GROUP:

```json
db.getCollection('students').aggregate([
   { $match: { status: "ACTIVE" } },
   { $group: { _id: { name : "$name"},
         date1 : { $max : "$date1" } ,
         city : { $max : "$city" } } }
])
```

**The wanted result:**

```json
{ "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "ANA", "date1" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:14:30.000Z") }
{ "city" : "RIO DE JANEIRO", "name" : "MARIA", "date1" : ISODate("2021-02-01T11:10:00.000Z") }
{ "city" : "BRASILIA", "name" : "JOHH", "date1" : ISODate("2021-06-01T01:18:00.000Z") }
```

**But the result is this:**

```json
{ "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "ANA", "date1" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:14:30.000Z") }
{ "city" : "SAO PAULO", "name" : "MARIA", "date1" : ISODate("2021-02-01T11:10:00.000Z") }
{ "city" : "BRASILIA", "name" : "JOHH", "date1" : ISODate("2021-06-01T01:18:00.000Z") }
```

It is retrieving wrong data. For ANA and JOHN (only one document each) it's ok. **But MARIA has three documents and I need to retrieve all data from her document with the $max date and I'm retrieving "city" : "SAO PAULO" rather than "city" : "RIO DE JANEIRO" because operator $MAX is applied for this field too**. That is applied for all fields and the GROUP operator does not allow removing the MAX operator.

I don't know to fix it.
How to get whole document, filtering by "last date of every distinct name" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this aggregation pipeline:

- First `$match` as you have.
- Then `$sort` to get desired values in first position. This is used by next stage.
- Into `$group` aggregation you get the `$first` value (as the document is sorted, the first value will be the desired one).
- And last `$project` to get desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "date1": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$name"
      },
      "date1": {
        "$first": "$date1"
      },
      "city": {
        "$first": "$city"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "$_id.name",
      "city": 1,
      "date1": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZ8Z6a4blD2)

Comment: I would like to do the same thing, but this query returns the wrong document.  It doesn't return the latest date document for Maria.  It returns the latest date, but not latest time.

Comment: Hi @BaronYoung I've checked and for Maria return the latest date with the `status` as `ACTIVE`. There is a `$match` at the start of the pipeline to filter only actives objects, and the `ISODate` 11:15 is not active.

Comment: My apologies.  I missed the active/inactive filter.